# How to attach file in open email?

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

I want to add an attachment in open email.

```
Sub AddAttachment() 
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
    Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 
    'Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'this will create a new Email which I don't want
    Set myItem= thisEmail **I need help with this part**
    Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
    myAttachments.Add "D:\Documents\Q496.xlsx", olByValue, 1, "4th Quarter 1996 Results Chart" 
    myItem.Display 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Inspector.CurrentItem` property for retrieving a mail item if it is opened in the inspector window.

```
Sub AddAttachment() 
     Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
     Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 
     'Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'this will create a new Email which I don't want
     Set myItem= Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
     Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
     myAttachments.Add "D:\Documents\Q496.xlsx", olByValue, 1, "4th Quarter 1996 Results Chart" 
     myItem.Display 
   End Sub
```

If the mail item is selected in the `Explorer` window you need to use the `Selection` object for retrieving the currently selected item in the folder view:

```
Sub AddAttachment() 
     Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
     Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 
     'Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'this will create a new Email which I don't want
     Set myItem= Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
     Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
     myAttachments.Add "D:\Documents\Q496.xlsx", olByValue, 1, "4th Quarter 1996 Results Chart" 
     myItem.Display 
   End Sub
```

Comment: If the user is editing an inline reply, the `ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)` line must be replaced with `Set myItem= Application.ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse`